# BIRT extension for execute after each generation

Tags: birt, birt-emitter

I need to create an extesion to  "cleanup" some things after each report generation, the output format does not matter.

I need this because I created a script function extension to obtain a JDBC connection inside the scripts.

If the programmer forget to close this connection the "Cleanup Extension" must do the dirty work (like a garbage collector).

What extension I need to extend to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a invisible layout element at the very end of your report and add the cleanup code to its onCreate event (if you are using `RunAndRenderTask`).